# Is there a way to create program that can search a website for content changes?

Tags: c#, sccm

I am an SCCM Admin by trade, but I am looking to get more involved in software development and I create PowerShell scripts all the time to help me automate many tasks in my environment. However, I am now looking to start utilizing more object oriented .Net languages like C# and I wanted to know, specifically, if there is a way to query Microsoft's site to see when they have released the latest version of Power BI Desktop?

I want to do this, because I package up this application and deploy it with SCCM when the next version is released and I want to beat the users to it.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: using HtmlAgility pack you can check the page html and decide for changes.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f shoud be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you could use the WebClient class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to open the page and then do a comparison to a previously cached version or hash. But to be honest you'd just be reinventing the wheel when there are plenty of services around which will already do this for you. Here are a couple of examples:

https://visualping.io/

https://www.changedetection.com/

Comment: I had no idea there were services like that - that's GREAT! Thanks